# T(n) run time for a function of two inputs

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, analysis

How would you find a T(n) run-time (not the big O run time) for a function that has two inputs? Do you just consider the a input your 'n'?

```
int h(int a, int b) {
  if (a > 0) {
    return h(a-1, a+b);
  } 
  else {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case we just need to consider `a` since the length of this algorithm isn't dependent on b.

In other words since we can pass in 20000 or -2 for b and not impact our time in the slightest (ignoring the actual time of adding `a+b`) we shouldn't have to consider b in our calculations.

In a more general case, if the input did depend on `a` and `b` we would simply account for this in our time complexity function. In other words it would be `T(a, b)` not just `T(a)`.

Comment: Thats what I was thinking, but I guess I couldn't get the logic down until you explained it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

as this function recurs only on a and a is decreasing by 1 in each step, it would give linear complexity. So answer would be T(a).

Answer (score 0):

Given that for each and every (a,b)-pair the function value is zero - the recursion will always end in the else-branch - the compiler may be smart enough to reduce the code effectively to "return 0" for the whole body and leave all the if/else and recursion stuff out, resulting in O(1) complexity and corresponding run time.